# Android toolbar show title and subtitle only when AppBarLayout collepsed

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have activity with AppBarLayout ,CollapsingToolbarLayout and toolbar.
Setting title and subtitle from code. Initially i want toolbar hidden and show when Appbar layout collapsed, 
With my code its working (toolbar hide initially) but its showing toolbar title and subtitle always. How do i show title only when appbar layout collapse completely

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:titleEnabled="false"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Setting title and subtitle

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
    getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("sutitle");
```

[image]

Comment: You have to `setTitle` on the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Do NOT access `Toolbar` or `ActionBar` directly. Note that `CollapsingToolbarLayout` does NOT support subtitle.

Comment: how can i achieve this functionality

Comment: Option a) File an issue here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list, option b) Open source of CollapsingToolbarLayout, understand how it works and add the functionality you need. If you choose this way, consider open sourcing your solution as others may have similar needs. Thanks!

Comment: Option c) Do not use subtitle. Use two line title with the second line wrapped in [AbsoluteSizeSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/AbsoluteSizeSpan.html) or [RelativeSizeSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/RelativeSizeSpan.html).

Comment: thank you Eugen for giving direction

Comment: This popped up in my Twitter feed: http://android-arsenal.com/details/3/3110?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Android_Arsenal+%28The+Android+Arsenal%29

Comment: Hey Eugen I solve my problem. see my answer

Answer (score 2):

A simple `AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener` should do the trick using only built-in views:

```
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int offset) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            boolean toolbarCollapsed = Math.abs(offset) >= appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
            actionBar.setTitle(toolbarCollapsed ? yourTitle : "");
            actionBar.setSubtitle(toolbarCollapsed ? yourSubTitle : "");
        }
});
```

(This code originally was written in C# (Xamarin), not Java, so minor modifications may be needed)

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem using [ControllableAppBarLayout](https://gist.github.com/skimarxall/863585dcd7abde8f4153) in xml and handle its EXPAND, COLLAPSED, IDEAL event to show/ to set my TITLE and SUBTITLE using following approach.

```
 ControllableAppBarLayout appBarLayout = (ControllableAppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    appBarLayout.setOnStateChangeListener(new ControllableAppBarLayout.OnStateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStateChange(ControllableAppBarLayout.State toolbarChange) {
            switch (toolbarChange) {

                case COLLAPSED: {
                    Log.i(TAG, "COLLAPSED2");
                    if (mProfileDetails != null) {
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mProfileDetails.userDetails.userFullname);
                        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(Html.fromHtml("<small>" + mProfileDetails.userDetails.headline + "</small>"));
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case EXPANDED:
                    Log.i(TAG, "EXPANDED");
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
                    getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("");
                    break;

                case IDLE: // Just fired once between switching states
                    Log.i(TAG, "IDLE");
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
                    getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```